# Changing page color with pdf_document

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown

Experimenting with a custom template with Rmarkdown and am wondering whether anyone knows how to change the background color for PDF output from Rmarkdown.

I tried using:

```
includes:
  before_body: before_body.tex
```

Where `before_body.tex` contains `\pagecolor{Cornsilk}`

This almost works except for the title page where the `\maketitle` command is placed before the `before_body` content.

Anyone know of a way to do this so that it applies to the entire document?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried including it with `in_header` rather than `before_body`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. One issue with using `in_header` is that the `\pagecolor` LaTeX command has to come after `begin{document}`. However, I did find a way to do it with `in_header` in my situation (I am creating a report/book with a title page so that `\maketitle` occur right after `begin{document}`).

My `in_header` (which I copied and modified from one I found online) contains a custom titlepage `\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}`which gets invoked with `\maketitle`. I put the `pagecolor` command in there which did the trick.

If the format one is using doesn't have a title page, then I suspect putting the page color in `before_body` will do the trick since there isn't a `\maketitle` command that would create a title page before the page color is defined.